# undefined method `author=' for #<Class:0x9a785a8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

I am trying to assign the author of a post automatically when he posts or edits. I have defined a helper function in application_controller.rb which checks for the current user and returns the object if signed in. But I get this error, and I don't seem to understand what's going wrong.

application_controller.rb

```
  def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]   
  end
  helper_method :current_user
```

My controller action:

```
def create
    @article=Article.find(params[:article_id])
    @review=@article.reviews.assign_author(current_user.name).create(review_params)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

My model:

```
def self.assign_author(name)
    self.author=name
end
```

Can anyone point what is the mistake I am making? I am sure its pretty small, but I don't seem to get it.

Comment: Is `author` an attribute of `Review`?

Comment: Yes author is defined in Review model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@review = @article.reviews.assign_author(current_user.name).create(review_params)
```

This is not how you add a new element to a collection. Should be something like this

```
@review = @article.reviews.build(review_params)
@review.assign_author(current_user.name)
@review.save
```

And `assign_author` method should be instance method (no `self.`)

```
def assign_author(name)
  self.author = name
end
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Its always great to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to restructure a bit.

`@review=@article.reviews.assign_author(current_user.name).create(review_params)`

is not something I typically work with. Instead, I would do something like this:

```
def create
    @article=Article.find(params[:article_id])
    review=Review.create(review_params)
    review.assign_author(current_user.name)
    @article.add_review(review)
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
end
```

That's how I would normally expect a create method to look.

Comment: I pasted the wrong error code. Please have another look.

Comment: I see. Actually I am pretty new to Rails. But when I tweak my code as per your suggestion in review.rb it gives an error `undefined method update_attributes' for #<Class:0x8935860>` . Is something wrong at my end?

Comment: @SouvikDas `update_attribute`, not `update_attributes` however `update_attributes` should also be defined. Wait, is `author` associated with an actual model in a database?

Comment: I tried both of them. And ya author is associated to review.

Comment: Ok, I think I might see something. What does `@article.reviews` return? It's pluralized so it sounds like it's possible to have multiple reviews? If so are you attempting to call a method defined for a single object across multiple objects?

Comment: Article to reviews is an one to many relationship. What I am trying to do is, an user can post review only if he is signed in. This part is working fine. Next, I want to store the name of the person who wrote the post, automatically. This is what I am trying to implement but got stuck. Am I looking at it in a completely wrong way?

Comment: @SouvikDas I feel like you are. Mostly because the plural `reviews' seems like it will be returning multiple reviews, not just the one you want to edit. Check my answer edit

Comment: undefined method: add_review
Seems you were on the right track though.

Comment: @SouvikDas Well yes, `add_review` is something you'd have to create for handling adding to a collection. On occasion there's custom steps you want to do when adding to collection (calling helpers, setting initial values, etc) so I just suggested an intermediary method named how I would name something like that.

Answer (score 0):

`@article.reviews` returns a collection of reviews, so you have to apply the author for all of them:

```
@review=@article.reviews.map{ |review| review.assign_author(current_user.name) }.create(review_params)
```

Comment: This is also extremely messy. Is it possible to assign a creation scope?

Comment: No actually, I want to update the author's name only to the current review being created. Not all the reviews of the article.

Comment: One possible solution is using the [`scoping`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/scoping) method: `@article.reviews.where(author: current_user.name).scoping do ... end` and create the records inside of that scope.